# Trying to update an immutable variable in Blender (PYTHON)

Tags: python, for-loop, blender

I'm trying to print multiple tables using a for loop in blender. I have a variable (table_pos) that has the values of the table's x, y, and z axis, which control the position of the table. The issue I'm facing is that the tables keep printing on top of each other, instead of being printed in an order where a there is space between each table. Check code please:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

table_size = (10, 10) #(width, length) along x, y direction
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
  
table_pos = (x, y, z)
leg_len = 8
leg_thickness = 1
leg_pos = (table_size[0]- leg_thickness,  table_size[1]- leg_thickness, -(leg_len))


for i in range(5): 



bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location = table_pos)

bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(table_size[0], table_size[1], 0.2))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location= table_pos)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(leg_thickness, leg_thickness, leg_len))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-leg_pos[0], leg_pos[1], leg_pos[2]))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=table_pos)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(leg_thickness, leg_thickness, leg_len))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(leg_pos[0], leg_pos[1], leg_pos[2]))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=table_pos)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(leg_thickness, leg_thickness, leg_len))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(leg_pos[0], -leg_pos[1], leg_pos[2]))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=table_pos)
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(leg_thickness, leg_thickness, leg_len))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-leg_pos[0], -leg_pos[1], leg_pos[2]))

print("check table position: ")
print(table_pos)
print("check x and y")
print(x)
print(y)
x += 10
y += 10
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're expecting this code in the for-loop...:

```
x += 10
y += 10
```

To update the `table_pos` tuple, which you use for placing your tables. It doesn't work like that. You need to update `table_pos` inside the loop, rather than just once before the loop.

Move `table_pos = (x, y, z)` into the body of the loop.